# Passing data between components using typescript, react, react-router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm creating a large single page app with typescript (v1.8.10), react (v15.0.2), and react-router (v2.4.0) and I'm trying to find the best way to have data pass between components in the following type of scenario.  I've seen other questions that are somewhat similar, but not quite the same especially when considering the type safety that TypeScript provides and I'd like to take advantage of.

Lets say I have a car viewing application with the following components: ComparisonComponent, DetailsComponent, and SelectComponent.

The DetailsComponent will show details of a car model and has a "select car" button which will bring up the SelectComponent.  Once the user selects a car in the SelectComponent, the details of that car should be displayed in the DetailsComponent.

The ComparisonComponent will compare two car models and has 2 separate "select car" buttons (eg. button A and button B).  When the user clicks button A, the SelectComponent should be displayed.  Once the user selects a car in the SelectComponent, Car A should be displayed in the ComparisonComponent.  Similarly if user hits button B, selects a car in SelectComponent, then Car B should be displayed in ComparisonComponent.

So, I am envisioning having the following routes:

- "/details" -> DetailsComponent
- "/details/select" -> SelectComponent
- "/compare" -> ComparisonComponent
- "/compare/select" -> SelectComponent

So, my questions are what is the proper way using react and react-router to have the SelectComponent pass back the selected car?  Since the SelectComponent should be shared between the other components, once the user is done selecting a car, how does the CompareComponent know whether it was Car A or Car B that was selected?  Since the SelectComponent is not a child of either DetailsComponent or CompareComponent, I don't think I can pass state from DetailsComponent or CompareComponent via props.  So, how would I pass data between those different routes using react router?

What would be the proper flux way of handling this type of scenario?  Would I create a details store and a compare store to keep track of the component specific data as the user navigates?  It seems like that would lead to keeping a lot of UI specific data in stores, when that UI specific data is no longer used.  It seems to me that it would waste a lot of memory especially for a large single page app that will end up having 100+ routes.   How do I keep from showing stale data if the user exits and reenters either the DetailsComponent or the CompareComponent?

Thanks for any help that you guys can provide.

Comment: I would use `redux`. It uses a single store and solves all your problems. It's also the current official flux implementation. Keeping UI specific data in stores is no different than keeping UI specific data anywhere else, you just need to listen to actions to invalidate / fetch new data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Since stores are singletons, doesn't that mean you are essentially keeping your UI state in globals?  Isn't that generally thought of as bad practice.  Also, by keeping all transient UI state in stores, I'll be hanging onto ui state data that is no longer valid or needed (eg a component that has been dismissed).  For a really large single page app, wouldn't this waste a lot of memory?  For redux, I have concerns about the single state store in a large single page app, couldn't it become a potential bottleneck?

Comment: 1) regarding unused state.. this is not a problem because it's trivial to dispatch actions which reset or clear state. 2) global state (single source of truth) is absolutely best practice because these are read only, often immutable values, and you know exactly the 'state' of your state at all times and how your state changes through actions. globals are bad for different reasons but perfect here. Your bottlenecks will not be because of redux architecture, but instead making sure that things aren't re-rendered or dispatched when they don't need to (no props have changed etc)